# Storing Huge Data; Database, XML or Plain text?

Tags: python, mysql, xml, database

I want to help my friend to analyze Posts on Social Networks (Facebook, Twitter, Linkdin and etc.) as well as several weblogs and websites.

When it comes to the **Storing the Data**, I have no experience in huge data. Which one is the best for a bunch of thousand post, tweet and article per day: Database, XML file, plain text? If database, which one?

P.S.
The language that I am going to start programming with is Python.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the way you want to work with the data. If you have structured data, and want the exchange it between different programs, xml might be a good choice. If you do mass processing, plain text might be a good choice. If you want to filter the data, a database might be a good choice.